# How to utilize class as object and then use two methods to test code?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I'm still very much a novice when it comes to coding in java, so while this seems like a very simple problem I just can't for the life of me figure out how to solve it. So originally I have this code with an interface like this:

```
public interface Animal {
    public String getSound();
    public String getType();
}
```

Then classes that define the sound and type of an animal such as:

```
public class Cow implements Animal{
    String color;
    public Cow(String c) {
        color = c;
    }
    public String getSound() {
        return "moo";
    }
    public String getType() {
        return "cow";
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

And then I have a class that puts all of the information together and print it out:

```
public class OldMacDonaldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal c;
        c = new Cow("brown");
        System.out.println("The " + ((Cow) c).getColor() + " " +c.getType() + " goes " + c.getSound());
        
        c = new Chick(3);
        System.out.println("The " + ((Chick) c).getAge() + " days old " + c.getType() + " goes " + c.getSound());
        
        c = new Sheep("fluffy");
        System.out.println("The " + ((Sheep) c).getTrait1() + " " + c.getType() + " goes " + c.getSound());
        
        c = new Dog("loyal");
        System.out.println("The " + ((Dog) c).getTrait2() + " " + c.getType() + " goes " + c.getSound());
    }
}
```

But then, I had to create this new farm class which uses arrays to test all the animals:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Farm{
    private ArrayList <Animal> myFarm;
    public Farm() {
        myFarm = new ArrayList <Animal>();
    }
    public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
        myFarm.add(animal);
    }
    public void animalSounds() {
        Animal a;
        for (int i=0; i < myFarm.size(); i++) {
            a = myFarm.get(i);
            System.out.println(a.getType() + " goes " + a.getSound());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to alter the OldMacDonaldApp class code so that I can create an object Farm and use methods addAnimal and animalSounds. I know this is probably really simple and I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I cannot wrap my brain around what to do. Any possible help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you know how to create an instance of a class because you are already doing it with (e.g.) `Cow`. That's how you create your `Farm`. Then you call methods on your farm instance the same way you are already calling them on your animal instances.

Answer (score 0):

The `Farm` class now does all the work, so we can simply create and add the animals with the `addAnimal(...)` method, and then use the `animalSounds()` method to print them all out:

```
public class OldMacDonaldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create the farm object the same way as creating a new animal
        Farm myFarm = new Farm();

        //Add animals to the farm using the addAnimal method of the Farm
        myfarm.addAnimal(new Cow("brown"));
        myfarm.addAnimal(new Chick(3));
        myfarm.addAnimal(new Sheep("fluffy"));
        myfarm.addAnimal(new Dog("loyal"));

        //Now print the sounds with the animalSounds method in the Farm class
        myfarm.animalSounds();
    }
}
```